# Reconstruction of FOL language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

If we have a FOL language $S$ and we suddenly lost its logical structure $\left(\rightarrow,\wedge,\vee,\bot,\top,\forall x,\exists x\right)$, can we recover it (modulo a logical equivalence) using only the logical consequence relation: $\models$ ?

Let's consider $S$ the set of formulas of a first order logic and $\bar S$ its quotient set by the logical equivalence relation ($\equiv$).

All logical connectives over $\bar S$ can be obviously expressed using only $\models$, for example: $$\bar p\rightarrow\bar q=\left\{r\in S\ |\ \forall s\in S,s\models r\Leftrightarrow s,p\models q\right\}$$

Now, and in order to reconstruct quantifiers, let's consider the following set :
$$ \Pi = \left\{\pi\in\big(\bar S^\bar S\big)^*\ \middle\vert\ \begin{array}{l}
    \forall p\in\bar S, (\pi\ p\models p)\wedge(\pi\ \pi\ p=\pi\ p) \\
    \forall p,q\in\bar S, \pi\ (\pi\ p\rightarrow\pi\ q)=\pi\ p\rightarrow\pi\ q\\
    \forall p\in\bar S,\Gamma\subseteq\bar S,\Gamma\models p\Rightarrow \pi\ \Gamma \models \pi\ p
  \end{array}\right\} $$
I think that elements of $\Pi_e=\left\{\pi\in\Pi,\exists!\left(\pi_1,\pi_2\right)\in\Pi^2,\pi=\pi_1\circ\pi_2\right\}$ are universal quantifiers (i.e.
$ p\mapsto\forall x, p[a\leftarrow x] $ where $x$ doesn't occur in $p$ and $a$ is a variable or a constant) plus circular substitutions conjunctions: $$p\mapsto\bigwedge_{i<n}p\left[x_0\leftarrow x_i,...,x_k\leftarrow x_{(k+i \mod n)},...,x_{n-1}\leftarrow x_{(n-1+i \mod n)}\right]$$
Where $(x_i)_i$ can be variables, functions or relations of the same arity.

Is this claim true in intuitionist FOL and in classic FOL ?

If the hole subject is already discussed, could someone please refer me to appropriate articles, and thanks a lot.

---

**EDIT:** To be more clear, I'm asking about recovering the logical signature up to a logical equivalence. So we can determine some relation between formulas equivalence classes like: $\overline{\forall x, P(x)}$ is a result of an application of universal quantifier on $\overline{P(x)}$ while $\overline{P(x)\wedge Q(x)}$ is not.

---

**EDIT:** And since this is not possible in general, is it possible at least when the non logical signature is finite and contains at least one non-zero arity relation and one non-zero arity function ?

Comment: Note that you seem to be juggling between *sentences* and *formulas* a bit, here; it ultimately makes no difference, but working with sentences only makes things messier (since in general $\forall x\varphi(x)$ can be a sentence without $\varphi(x)$ being a sentence).

Comment: Yes, you have reason, I'm sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Formulas make the situation even easier: any permutation of the variables induces an automorphism of $\mathcal{B}$. For this reason I've left my answer mostly as is, since the interesting situation is when we restrict attention to sentences.

(The above assumes that we don't identify a formula with its universal closure; if we do, then the situation is the same as for sentences since every formula is equivalent to a sentence, namely its universal closure.)

---

No, you cannot do this in general: when we look at the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of semantic equivalence classes of $S$-sentences (which is what you're left with when you forget everything except "$\models$" - incidentally, this is the [Lindenbaum algebra of the empty theory over $S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra)), this algebra has lots of nontrivial automorphisms - these will send sentences to non-equivalent sentences while preserving the $\models$-structure.

Under weak hypotheses on $S$ *(let's assume $S$ is countable for now)* we can prove this quickly. If $S$ contains two distinct symbols of the same type (e.g. two constant symbols, or two $17$-ary relation symbols, or etc.), then swapping them induces a nontrivial automorphism of $\mathcal{B}$. More complicatedly, if $S$ is infinite then $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable atomless Boolean algebra, and these are homogeneous (given any two elements neither of which is $0$ or $1$, there is an automorphism swapping them); this is proved by a back-and-forth argument, similar to that presented in [this proof that any two countable atomless Boolean algebras are isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358772/any-two-countable-atomless-boolean-algebras-are-isomorphic). Similarly, if $S=\emptyset$ then any permutation of the sentences of the form "there are exactly $n$ elements" induces an automorphism of $\mathcal{B}$.

I believe in fact that we can *never* perform the reconstruction you want, but I don't have a proof of that yet. Note in particular that we can produces examples of $S$ where some elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are atoms but other elements don't lie above any atoms, so it's neither atomless nor "atomful;" this complicates the picture a bit.

---

The picture for intuitionistic logic will be similar, except with [Heyting algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra) taking the role of Boolean algebras. In general, any logic allowing a significant amount of reconstruction along the lines you're proposing would have to be very "algebraically restrictive" (in the sense of [algebraic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_logic)), and I'm not aware of any natural such logics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I have made a mistake, I wrote sentences instead of formulas. Can you please, see it again :)

Comment: @AhmedLazhar: That doesn't really change anything, because usually we consider a non-sentence formula and its universal closure to entail each other. So each of the equivalence classes are going to contain some sentences anyway.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not sure how usual that is. I think things are almost always more interesting without it. It certainly makes quantification nicer, since $\forall xP(x)$ and $\forall xP(y)$ are inequivalent even though the universal closures of $P(x)$ and $P(y)$ are equivalent.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, And what if the signature is finite ? For example, let's consider our signature with two relations $P(x)$ and $R(x,y)$ then $\forall x\forall y(P(x)\wedge Q(x,y)\wedge x=y)$ is an atom. If the logic is not with equality or we required the existence of infinity of elements, then $\forall x\forall y(P(x)\wedge Q(x,y))$ would be an atom. Is that true ? In that case what can be the elements of my $\Pi$ ? I have to mention that what I'm looking for is to reconstruct the logical signature. There is no problem if I swap two symbols as long as the hole sentence structure is recovered.

Comment: Even if we add $\neg\forall x\forall y(P(x)\wedge R(x,y))$ as an axiom, can't we take as atom $\forall x\forall y\ne a(P(x)\wedge R(x,y))$ if the logic is with equality and $\forall x\forall y(P(x)\wedge R(x,f(y)))$ otherwise ?

Comment: We can't take $\forall x\forall y(P(x)\wedge R(x,f(y)))$ as an atom because it follows from $\forall x\forall y(P(x)\wedge R(x,f(y))\wedge R(x,a))$. So let's forget about logic without equality and focus only on FOL with equality.